# Keeping track of liquidated stock positions in a DF?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a bunch of stock transactions and I'm trying to track how many times i have sold off my entire positions in a given security in order to calculate the correct average buy amount for my most recent held position and net/loss for my previously liquidated positions.

Simplified example DF:

```
import pandas as pd


test = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [180201,190403,190609,190611,190912,191014,200101],
                     'Ticker': ['stockA', 'stockA', 'stockA', 'stockA', 'stockA', 'stockA', 'stockA'],
                     'Amount': [30, -10, -20, 20, -20, 10, 50],
                     'Total': [-30000, 35000, 35000, -40000, 23000, -60000, -30000],
                     'Transaction': ['Buy', 'Sell', 'Sell', 'Buy', 'Sell', 'Buy', 'Buy']})

     Date  Ticker  Amount  Total Transaction
0  180201  stockA      30 -30000          Buy
1  190403  stockA     -10  35000         Sell
2  190609  stockA     -20  35000         Sell
3  190611  stockA      20 -40000          Buy
4  190912  stockA     -20  23000         Sell
5  191014  stockA      10 -60000          Buy
6  200101  stockA      50 -30000          Buy
```

From the above given DF I want to calculate my amount currently held (and the total/amount) and the net profit/loss of my sold off positions. My only idea that came to mind was to add a new column to mark which position have been sold by iterating row for row with something like this:

```
counter = test['Amount'].add(test['Amount'].shift(-1))
for i in range(0, len(test)):
    if counter.loc[i] == 0:
        test.loc[i, 'Liquidated'] = 1
    else:
        test.loc[i, 'Liquidated'] = 0
```

This does obviously not take into account if something is partially sold off and would need to skip the last row for the next count is the previous one was zero. I cannot really wrap my head around how to achieve this.

Comment: Should it not be liquidated when `<= 0` rather than `== 0`? Also how is `Total` being calculated?

Comment: Correct, in certain real world circumstances it would be less than zero but chose to represent it as zero here just to simplify things

Comment: can you show a sample output? if possible

Comment: Your df above is not the same as your table, there are some differences in signs. I guess the 'Total' array should be `[-30000, 35000, 35000, -40000, 23000, -60000, -30000]`. Btw, to get your current position at any time, you could do `df["currPosition"] = df["Amount"].cumsum()`

Comment: Fixed the array, ty! Thanks for the cumsum() hint, that will come in handy. Could maybe in some way use the result of cumsum() and work backwards from the latest date until the total of the buy column is equal to that and then just net sum the total for all the rows before that